# Node.js/Express: Should I make multiple calls or just one big call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server that needs to write about 100 html files into a directory in the project root.

I can build this server in 2 ways: the server can receive the request from the browser then start the 100 requests and send back a 200 when it finishes, or 
I can send a 200 after every successful file write and just go back and forth like that for every file.

My question is, when using express/node.js, which is better performance wise?

In scenario 1, should the server just be sitting there doing all that work for multiple users? Will I run into memory issues? Because 
I could put that list of files in the browser and make separate calls to my node server to retrieve and write each file from the external API.

This is what that first scenario sort of looks like. The route gets a list of files, then makes a call for each file.

```
//this whole request takes about 3 minutes to complete due to rate limiting of the external APIs.
router.get('/api/myroute', (req, res, next) => {

    //contact a remote server's API, it sends back a big list of files.
    REMOTE_SERVER.file_list.list(USER_CREDS.id).then(files => {

        //we need to get the contents of each specific file, so we do that here.
        Promise.all(files.map((item, i) =>
            //they have an API for specific files, but you need the list of those files first like we retrieved above.
            //more specifically you need a key for each file that is in the file_list object.
            REMOTE_SERVER.specific_file.get(USER_CREDS.id, {
                file: { key: files[i].key }
            }).then(asset => {

                //write the contents of each file to a directory called "my_files" in the project root.
                fs.writeFile('./my_files/' + file.key, file.value, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    };
                });
            })))
            //send back a 200 only when the entire list has been retrieved and written to our directory. 
            .then(() => {
                console.log("DONE!!");
                res.status(200).send();
            })
    });
});
```

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274340/many-small-requests-vs-few-large-requests-api-design

Comment: Uhhh, you can only send one http response per request so not sure how you could possibly send a 200 after every successful write.  That part of your question makes no sense at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 step 1. Get array of files you need to retrieve 2. Pop one file off the array with its key and send it to the node server 3. on the server side go fetch the file with that data and then write what you get back 4. do it again for the rest of the array sitting in your browser

Comment: Well, it's not good to have the client make N requests when 1 will do, so I would not have the client do N requests.  node.js is particularly good at interleaving asynchronous I/O related tasks with processing incoming requests (when neither is CPU intensive) so it should be no problem for the server to be doing a bunch of async file I/O while still handling other requests.  You could also start a child node.js process that would handle the long running tasks, but chances are that isn't necessary.